How do large geospatial libraries such as shapely, ArcPy, GeoPandas perform geometric intersections? What algorithms are used?
I'm trying to perform millions geometric intersections between two line files projected in a UTM coordinate system. The operation is quite large so I've attempted to parallelize it on the GPU using CUDA to speed up the operation. This involved writing my own intersection logic using vector cross products and parametric equations. The result of the operation is good but is slightly off (~1 meter) when compared to intersections performed in ArcGIS Pro, shapely, or GeoPandas. I'm assuming there is some background work done on the shapefiles before intersection operations are performed by tools in these large geospatial libraries to account for the curvature of the Earth.
What math is performed to account for the Earth's curvature?
I followed this document https://www.boeing-727.com/Data/fly%20odds/distance.html closely and still wound up with the same offset.

Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which emphasizes the importance of askinging One question per Question. Unfortunately, you have at least five questions here, one (or more) of which requires access to proprietary source to be answered. Cartesian calculations don't require curvature unless you force them to, and multiplexes the questions already here. We can't possibly guess what is different about your code and the others. Please [Edit] the Question to ask an answerable question.

There are better ways to parallelize that don't require you to write your own algorithm.  For instance,you could dissect the bounding boxes into a grid of smaller cells, clip each file to a small outer buffer of each cell (a highly parallelizable operation), perform the intersections (in parallel) within each cell, and assemble the results, resolving any duplicates within the buffer overlaps.  (You use buffers to avoid creating artificial intersection points on the cell boundaries.)

At least shapely doesn't do anything with curvature of the earth. First line of the shapely doc: Manipulation and analysis of geometric objects in the Cartesian plane..
Same for geopandas, as it uses shapely under the hood for these operations.
So, if there is a difference, there must be another explanation. Shapely is actually a python wrapper around geos. This is a C++ open source library, so you can check out the algorithms here.
Note that the typical way to speed up calculating overlays between many geometries is to use a spatial index, so you might want to look into that. You can find an example of its use and potential performance improvement here. When you use geopandas.overlay, it will use a spatial index as well.
If this doesn't give a sufficient speedup, you can also have a look at geofileops. This is a library I developed that offers a higher level API and uses spatial indexes, GEOS,... under the hood combined with parallelisation on the CPU. Its input should be geopackage files for optimal performance: geofileops.intersection.

Thanks Pieter, I think I found the answer to the offset issue. ArcGIS Pro will densify points along line segments when they are sufficiently long in order to correct for map distortion. In my case, I created multiple 100km long line segments defined in a UTM projection using a single start and end coordinate with the XYToLine tool in arcpy. It turns out ArcGIS Pro densified multiple vertices along these line segments, a phenomenon I observed when reading the SHAPE@ attribute of the line shapefile with a cursor. So, Arc uses densified line segments to perform intersections, minimizing error.

I don't quite understand how densifying the segments can minimize errors, rather the opposite in my opinion. I rather think the points are added by a tiling process to improve performance. In geofileops I use this trick as well in some situations.
